# swift query how to detect if no results found?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I would like to display message when query didn't found any results, How can i do that?

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects, error) -> Void in

    if error == nil
    {
        for object in objects! {

            self.users.append(object.objectForKey("username") as! String)

            self.rtable.reloadData()
            print("username found!")
        }
```

Any help please?

Comment: When you get errors, then check to see if error has something and it will have something. Thats when you trigger the Alert.

Comment: @kandelvijaya Thank you, But it always show me no error, And there's no results!

Comment: that might be due to the fact that the query does not have any results to give you back. But its unclear to me what you want to accomplish. Let me know if your program crashes or more info i can help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would say you check the else case. When Parse/or the server gives you error then it will put the contents of as why error occurred or the error code in the error object refrece type. Check that if it does have something, if it does then we got some error message. Thats a good time to see what error happened and alert the user nicely.

Basically i would suggest to look at the error and see if its network problem, data type inconsistency or something specific which if presented to user, user might be empowered to correct it for the next time.

I hope you got the point. Cheers! Let me know if i can help you more.

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && object != nil{
            if object!.count > 0{
            //there are some matching cases
            self.users.append((object as! [PFObject]).first.objectForKey("username") as! String)

            self.rtable.reloadData()
            print("username found!")
            }else{  print("No match Found");  }
        }else if error != nil{
            //we do have some error
            UIAlertView(title: "Error!", message: "why error message", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "GotIt!").show()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!, Is that just to detect errors and why query isn't worked? I want to detect if query searched for username and didn't found the username, Like you want to search for "Kandel" And then you'll get message " Sorry Kandel didn't found in our backend" , did you got it what i want ?

Comment: Yes you can do that. in the message part "Sorry \(username) not found".

Comment: If you want more help, just provide some more context as what you would like to do. I think thats how i do Parse error handling mostly if i need to.

Comment: I don't know i'm so confused because i just wrote print("success") in if error== nil , And I always getting success message also if the name not found, Any idea ?

Comment: Oh, i get it check to see the objects. do that if object?.count > 0{  print("success") }

Comment: I tried that not working, When i print(objects!) , I get [] output

Comment: i really think you don't have anything on server. Not having a match on server is not error. Error is due to bad query, network or logic error.

Comment: So Is there anyway to detect if there's no match ?